# Host headers for SharePoint foundation

Tags: host-header, standalone

Can we configure host headers for SharePoint Standalone environment? without Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. AD doesn't play a role here. Have you already created one, you can recreate it by removing SharePoint from the IIS Web Site on your Web Application in Central Administration. When that is done, extend your Web Application, chose an existing IIS Site but with a new Host Header.

Reference: [How to properly change the Host Header URL of a web application in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/02/27/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to change any host header, I want to create a new web application with new host header, how will I do that while I don't have DNS? isn't DNS necessary to insert HOST A record?